# Class member functions definitions in separate libraries, and link dependencies

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, member

Given a class C defined in C.h, 
and member functions f1 to fn, and member function g1.

f1..fn's definitions are in f.cpp while g1's is in g.cpp.

f.cpp is linked into lib1.so while g.cpp is linked into lib2.so.

g.cpp depends on C.h,and lib2.so depends on lib1.so.
But lib1.so doesn't no depend on lib2.so

When I have executable that uses C members except g1() and I try to link it against lib1.so only, the linking fails with unresolved references:

lib1.so : unresolved reference to C::g1()  (which is defined in lib2.so)

If the code in the executable doesn't actually directly use g1, should I be able to have linking independent of lib2 entirely?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to split member functions of one class into two separate libraries?

Comment: same functionality, serial run, parallel run.
1 Binary is only interested in the serial run, and another binary in the parallel run.

Comment: This design feels weird to me. I understand that `f1()` and `g1()` are equivalent (one is serial, other is parallel), right? So the user of the class has to know which one is which and use them accordingly. Both binaries have to know about both implementations (because both are part of the class). Why not split that into class hierarchy with base class implementing f2 to fn with one pure virtual method `run()`, and then two classes which implement `run()` with either serial or parallel approach?

Comment: Answering for the question: it's not possible with that design. Linker must have a definition for every function declaration it sees. So, if your class in header contains `f1()` and `g1()`, you must provide both definitions whenever that header is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you have done is you've put g1() prototype into C.h, so you must provide implementation for it as @Yksisarvinen commented already.

What you probably want to do in your second library is create D.h with g1() prototype or possibly subclass class from C.h in D.h and put new implementation (from g1()) for your D::f1()

Even better using abstract class to define interface and provide 2 implementations. Quick example of what I would do:

```
//iface.h
class iface
{
public:
    virtual void f1() = 0;
}
//serial.h & cpp
class serial: public iface
{ 
public:
    final void f1(); //serial implementation in .cpp
}

//para.h & .cpp
class para: public iface
{
public:
    final void f1(); //parallel implementation in .cpp
}
```